# Microsoft Translate API is not working properly

Tags: c#, api, microsoft-translator

I am trying to convert English text to Hindi text. For that I am using Microsoft Text translator API. But some of my text is not translating.

After googling I have found below code.

```
 public string GetHindiText(string textToTranslate)
    {
        Carrier.ErrorCode = 0;
        string TranslatedText = string.Empty;
        try
        { 
            Translator.LanguageServiceClient objTranslate = new Translator.LanguageServiceClient();
            TranslatedText = objTranslate.Translate("***************", textToTranslate, "en", "hi");
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            Carrier.ErrorCode = 1;
            return ex.Message;
        }
        return TranslatedText;
    }
```

And I have added below service reference

**http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V1/SOAP.svc**

Most of the text is not translating. I need your suggestions to move forward.
Am I doing in correct way or anything I need to change. Any help is greatly helpful to me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to the NuGet package [NequeoNetTranslator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NequeoNetTranslator/), this contains text and speech translation APIs.

Sample of text translation this uses the new `Cognitive` version, first get your access token, through your translation [KEY]:

```
Nequeo.Net.Translator.Microsoft.Cognitive.Api apiat = new Nequeo.Net.Translator.Microsoft.Cognitive.Api(new Uri("https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/"));
apiat.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("[KEY]", "[KEY]");
string token = apiat.GetAccessToken();
```

Now call the translate method , this will translate `en` to`de`:

```
Nequeo.Net.Translator.Microsoft.Cognitive.Api api = new Nequeo.Net.Translator.Microsoft.Cognitive.Api(new Uri("https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/http.svc/"));
api.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("[KEY]", "[KEY]");
byte[] data = api.Translate("hello", "de", "en", null, token);
Translation[] tran = api.Translate(data);
string tranText = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
```

If you are using speech to text then sample code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Nequeo.Net.Translator.Microsoft.Cognitive.SpeechApi apiat = null;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        apiat = new Nequeo.Net.Translator.Microsoft.Cognitive.SpeechApi(new Uri("wss://dev.microsofttranslator.com/speech/"));
        apiat.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("[KEY]", "[KEY]");
        string token = apiat.GetAccessToken(new Uri("https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/"));

        apiat.OnRecording += Apiat_OnRecording;
        apiat.OnStopRecording += Apiat_OnStopRecording;
        apiat.OnTranslationReceived += Apiat_OnTranslationReceived;

        Nequeo.IO.Audio.Device device_in = Nequeo.IO.Audio.Devices.GetDeviceIn(0);
        apiat.AudioDevice = device_in;
        apiat.WriteStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

        apiat.Translate("hr-HR", "en-US", token);
    }

    private void Apiat_OnTranslationReceived(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.IO.MemoryStream jj = (System.IO.MemoryStream)apiat.WriteStream;

        string gg = Encoding.Default.GetString(jj.ToArray());

        Nequeo.Net.Translator.Microsoft.Cognitive.SpeechTranslation dffddf = apiat.GetSpeechTranslation();
    }

    private void Apiat_OnStopRecording(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool kk = true;

    }

    private void Apiat_OnRecording(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool kk = true;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        apiat.StopTranslate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Am I need to subscribe for Microsoft Azure Cognitive services to get the Key ? Is it paid services?

Comment: Refer to [TranslatorAPI](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/translator-api), go to the bottom of the page for pricing: Translator Text API and Translator Speech API.